# How to set group (like that for GtkRadioButton) for GtkToggleButton in GTK+?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, glade

How to set group (like that for GtkRadioButton) for GtkToggleButton in GTK+ ? What is the properties i can use for this aim. I want to check buttons, which set the drawing primitive (rectangle, ellipse, etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a group of buttons where only one can be turned on at a time, but looking like regular buttons instead of radio buttons.

Use radio buttons, and add them to a group as usual, but set the `draw-indicator` property to `FALSE`. They will be drawn like regular buttons.

Comment: _Thank you._ (both!) I knew I had seen this option before but couldn't find it again, so I've been Googling and Ctrl+Fing in the docs for ages using seemingly more logical but fruitless words. Only now did I think of typing _gtkradiobutton look like gtktogglebutton_ and so find this thread. :-)